# Multi threaded UDP server with Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, netty

I'm trying to implement a UDP server with Netty. The idea is to bind only once (therefore creating only one `Channel`). This `Channel` is initialized with only one handler that dispatches processing of incoming datagrams among multiple threads via an `ExecutorService`.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Dispatcher dispatcher;

    private String host;

    private int port;

    @Bean
    public Bootstrap bootstrap() throws Exception {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
            .group(new NioEventLoopGroup(1))
            .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
            .handler(dispatcher);

        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(host, port).await();
        if(!future.isSuccess())
            throw new Exception(String.format("Fail to bind on [host = %s , port = %d].", host, port), future.cause());

        return bootstrap;
    }
}

@Component
@Sharable
public class Dispatcher extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter implements InitializingBean {

    private int workerThreads;

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        DatagramPacket packet = (DatagramPacket) msg;

        final Channel channel = ctx.channel();

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Process the packet and produce a response packet (below)              
                DatagramPacket responsePacket = ...;

                ChannelFuture future;
                try {
                    future = channel.writeAndFlush(responsePacket).await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
                if(!future.isSuccess())
                    log.warn("Failed to write response packet.");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(workerThreads);
    }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Should the `DatagramPacket` received by the `channelRead` method of the `Dispatcher` class be duplicated before being used by the worker thread? I wonder if this packet is destroyed after the `channelRead` method returns, even if a reference is kept by the worker thread.
2. Is it safe to share the `Channel` among all the worker threads and let them call `writeAndFlush` concurrently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Nope. If you need the object to live longer you either turn it into something else or use `ReferenceCountUtil.retain(datagram)` and then `ReferenceCountUtil.release(datagram)` once you're done with it. You also shouldn't be doing `await()` at the executor service as well, you should register a handler for whatever happens.
2. Yes, channel objects are thread safe and they can be called from many different threads.